# jaxb prints unknown source when generating xbrl schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xbrl

I used jaxb before to generate java code from a xsd to easily prints xml files afterwards.

Now I want to use jaxb to generate a xbrl report. I use xjc as follows:

```
xjc.exe "http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/10.0/report/bd/entrypoints/bd-rpt-ob-aangifte-2016.xsd" -verbose -d "D:\Test\src" -p xso.bd.aangifte2016
```

The output is:
`parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[INFO] generating code
unknown location`

Result: no sources are generated

It does not say which location is unknown. I think xjc cannot deal with relative paths in the xsd, but I am not sure about it.

Does anyone know how to generated java code for this xsd?

Thanks.

Comment: I now know: the message 'unknown location' has nothing to do with the paths in the document. I thinks it is not the reason why there are no sources generated. Does anyone know how to generate sources for this kind of xsd?

Answer (score -1):

It should print the location like where the files are put after `unknown location` line.

and it should create and put the generated files in `xso.bd.aangifte2016` folder hierarchy. That is, inside your destination directory specified using `-d` flag.

So, generated files will be in - `D:\Test\src\xso\bd\aangifte2016\`.

Comment: Thats what you could expect yes, but it is not. No path after the unknown location and no generated sources.

Comment: dont know whether you have resolve it or not ... try escaping the \ in destination path i.e, change `D:\Test\src` to `"D:\\Test\\src"`. Just a thought.